# Upload Image to Cloudinary with React and Apollo(GraphQL)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, cloudinary

### Objective

I want to upload a image to Cloudinary which the user uploads from the react frontend.
This following program gives the error `ENAMETOOLONG` probably because the image gets converted to BASE64 type.

### React Upload Component Code

```
const UploadImageComponent = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [fileInput, setFileInput] = useState('')
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('')
    const [previewSource, setPreviewSource] = useState();

    function handleSubmit(e){
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        previewFile(file);
    }

    const previewFile = (file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            setPreviewSource(reader.result)
        }
    }

    const handleSubmitFile = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(!previewSource) return;
        uploadImage()
    }
    const [addImage] = useMutation(ADD_IMAGE, {
        variables: {
            userID: user.id,
            photo: JSON.stringify(previewSource)
        }
    })
    const uploadImage = () => {
       addImage();
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitFile}>
            <Form.Input 
                type="file"
                name="image"
                onChange={handleSubmit}
                value= {fileInput}
            />
            <Button type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
        {previewSource && (
            <img src={previewSource} alt="coolest-ever" style={{height: '300px', width: '300px'}}/>
        )}
        </>
    )
}
```

### MUTATION IN REACT TO SEND

```
const ADD_IMAGE = gql`
    mutation($userID: ID!, $photo: String!){
        addImage(userID: $userID, photo: $photo){
            id 
        }
    }
`
```

### Mutation Resolver

```
 async addImage(_, { userID, photo }, context){  //photo is given as type: String!
            const user = checkAuth(context);

            if(!user) throw new AuthenticationError('Not Logged In')

            const imgUpload = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo)
            
            let userProfile = await User.findById(userID)
                
            if(user){

                await User.updateOne({_id: userID}),{
                    $set: {
                        photo: imgUpload.url
                    }
                }

                const newUserProfile = await User.findById(userID)

                return newUserProfile
            }else{
                throw new Error('Unknown Error')
            }
            
        }
```

### What is needed

I want to make it so that when the user uploads an image it gets pushed to my Cloudinary space and the image URL from Cloudinary gets stored on my MongoDb collection, so that when I use them in my program I can put the URL in a simple `img src={user.photo}`, and it displays.

### Note

This is my first React Project so this was the first idea that came to my mind, I am sure there are better ideas too, please do answer if there are better ways to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code on how to upload using React:

```
  formdata.append("file", file);
    formdata.append("cloud_name", "<cloud name>");
    formdata.append("upload_preset", "<upload preset>");

    let res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/shirly/auto/upload",
      {
        method: "post",
        mode: "cors",
        body: formdata
      }
    );

    let json = await res.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.secure_url));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Upload</h3>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.processFile} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Upload />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/jq4wl1xjv?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js
Please note that you'll need to set your cloud name and unsigned upload preset in the right place.

As a side note, you might want to consider using [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget)
For example in React: http://jsfiddle.net/RayStra/gevc4ktm/